# jQuery hide elements and free space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, materialize

I am displaying a list of checkboxes using this code :

```
<div class="col m12 s12">

    <input id="search" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Compétence..." oninput="update();">

    {% for keyword in keywords %}
        <div class="col m4 s12">
            <p class="range-field">
                <input type="checkbox" id="{{loop.index}}" name="{{keyword.title}}" class="filled-in"/>
                <label for="{{loop.index}}">{{keyword.title}}</label>
                <input type="range" min="0" max="100"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

When I start searching, only elements matching the text are shown while others are hidden

```
function update()
{
    var res = $.trim($("#search").val());
    if(res === "")
    {
        $("label").parent().show();
    }
    else
    {
        contains_selector = "label:isLike("+res+")"
        $(contains_selector).parent().show();
        not_contains_selector = "label:not(:isLike("+res+"))"
        $(not_contains_selector).parent().hide();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when elements are hidden, they still take space as shown here

[image]

[image]

I would to know how can I completely free the space after hiding, just like remove() does.

I also tried changing visibility to hidden but it still does not work

I am using Materialize for frontend

Comment: You're hiding label's parent, which is p. Therefore <div md-4> still has its space. Try hiding the div instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you try to hide parent of label (`<p class="range-field">`), but you need to hide `<div class="col m4 s12">`

Try this:

```
$(contains_selector).closest(".col").show();
...
$(contains_selector).closest(".col").hide();
```

Comment: I used $("label").parent().parent().show(); and $(not_contains_selector).parent().parent().hide();and it worked. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: You can use `parent().parent()`, but if you change layout it maybe stop working.